# Pylint E1103 False Positive?

Tags: python, pylint

Following my previous question (["Pylint E0202 False Positive?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631666/pylint-e0202-false-positive-or-is-this-piece-of-code-wrong)) here is another one (quite specific I guess)

we are using the module subprocess to execute a, well, subprocess.
Creating an example code resulted in the following:

```
"Example code for E1103"

import subprocess

pipeOpen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

(responseData, errorData) = pipeOpen.communicate()

print "Error code: '%s'. Error data: '%s'" % (pipeOpen.returncode, errorData.strip("\n").strip("\r"))
```

Pylint will say though:

> E1103:  9,67: Instance of 'list' has no 'strip' member (but some types could not be inferred)

Looking in to pipeOpen.communicate() it goes down to _communicate. And indeed, stderr is initialised to a list, however, before the return if self.universal_newlines is true then it'll convert the list to a string with newlines.

Is this a case of `#pylint: ignore-msg=E1103` or better report it to pylint devs?

Comment: did you try to set `pipeOpen.universal_newlines = true`?

Comment: or `", ".join(errorData)` instead of `strip` if it is a list instead of a string?

Comment: @deathApril yes, this is being done in the Popen(). Will update code example to reflect our working code

Comment: see my answer or if you can use python 3.2 - `communicate()` will always return a tuple of 2 strings...

Comment: To disable a pylint message on a single line use `# pylint: disable=E1103` for Python 2.7 and Pylint-0.25.1, and not `ignore-msg` but maybe you are using a different version of Python/Pylint. See [Pylint User Manual: Message Control](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual#messages-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if `print(pipeOpen.universal_newlines and hasattr(file, 'newlines'))` returns `True` and you don't get any errors while actually running the code, then you should report this to pylint developers + ignore the message in the meantime

Comment: Sadly no python 3.x Stuck with ActiveState 2.7.2. Yes that line of code returns true in our case. Guess I'll report it as well. It feels quite ugly having to use a `pylint: ignore-msg=`. Thanks though :-)